# To specify or not specify all useEffect dependencies

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I've created this `useEffect` construct to first launch validation and then to POST the data if it passes validation:

```
  const isFirstRun = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRun.current) {
      isFirstRun.current = false;
      return;
    }

    if (isProcessing) {
      validate();
    } else {
      if (_.isEmpty(validationErrors)) {
        console.log('*** Ready to POST ***');

      }  
    }
  }, [isProcessing]);
```

I'm entirely fine with having just `isProcessing` as the only dependency for the `useEffect` but the VSCode linter is insisting that `validate` and `validationErrors` also be included.

I'm sure that adding `validate` would cause no problems but given that the validation code keeps adding items to `validationErrors`, I don't want this `useEffect` triggered every time it's changed.

How would you handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just becuase VSCode linter is suggesting it dosent make it best practice to follow.
You my friend is doing just fine by only triggering useEffect only and only when you require, in your case when isProcessing changes, this is perfect way to optimize and reduce load on application processing.

**Your case 1 : Adding validate**

You are somehow correct as function reference is not changing so it wont trigger useEffect

**Your case 2 : Adding validationErrors**

This could be a big issue if your `validate` function modifies `validationErrors` as it will create a big chain of `validationErrors`  modification which will result in calling `useEffect` infinitely in some specific cases.

So yes you can ignore those suggestion.
useEffect is a really great thing but one should be careful while handling it. :-)